# ActiveRecord/NHibernate: handling Lazy collections in a persistence-unaware context

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle-activerecord

My web application (MonoRail, Windsor, ActiveRecord) has a Startable import service and one or more Startable import readers. When, for example, a file is dropped in a directory, a reader parses the file, passes the data to the service, which updates and/or creates objects through repositories. The problem I have is that these Startable services live outside the request scope (where there's a SessionScope from Begin to End), so when the service encounters a lazy collection, there's no SessionScope around to help it do its magic. Cue LazyInitializationException :).

Any ideas how to solve this nicely? Perhaps using an interceptor to create and dispose a SessionScope around the method that processes the data? Equip the repositories with methods that perform eager fetching? I want to keep the services unaware of ActiveRecord, because my dependency paranoia says we might want to use a different persistence mechanism one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already answered it:

> using an interceptor to create and
>   dispose a SessionScope around the
>   method that processes the data

Comment: Hmm, yes... It's definitely neater than having to write all that eager-fetching HQL and what not. Adds a bit of configuration, but it's manageble. Any idea how/if I can configure an interceptor to intercept a specific method without having to code it into the interceptor itself?

Comment: You could have the interceptor take a string parameter that is the name of the method to intercept... then assign each interceptable component a different instance of the interceptor.

Comment: Another option would be decorating your interceptable methods with an attribute, then checking that attribute from the interceptor.

Comment: This is hardly the place to discuss this... please ask again on the forums (http://forum.castleproject.org/) or google group (http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users)